# Are these drainage holes? Or should I plug these?

Tags: bathroom, shower

New homeowner here. I have 2 small holes in the door to our shower/tub, are these drainage holes I should leave alone? Or something I should plug up?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are we looking at something which is vertical or horizontal?

Comment: Please [edit] to add one more picture that shows us a wider view so we can figure out _where_ this is on the tub/surround.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it is horizontal at the bottom of the shower door.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing those holes will drain will be water behind your wall. They look like they may have been from a previously installed shower door. I would be filling them in with grout just to be consistant with the tile grout or at least a high quality caulk. Push in some tissue or paper towel to make sure it's dry in there before sealing it up.

I'd swab/pour a little white vinegar down each hole to kill any mold the might already be there. Make sure that's dry before sealing.